# How to allow nullable boolean URI parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to let users retrieve data in three ways:

- If `isEven = null` (default)  then both even and odd numbers are returned.
- If `isEven = true` then even numbers are returned.
- If `isEven = false` then odd numbers are returned.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MathematicsController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("{isEven:bool?}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetData(bool? isEven = null)
    {
        var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).AsQueryable();

        if (isEven is not null)
            data = data.Where(x => (x % 2 == 0) == isEven);

        return Ok(data.ToList());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Swagger does not allow us to execute without selecting the dropdown box.  I already set the parameter with a trailing question mark (`{isEven:bool?}`) to represent that the parameter is optional. What am I missing here?

[image]

#### Addendum

I think Swagger UI is the culprit. I tested with Chrome by navigating to `https://localhost:40443/api/mathematics/getdata` (or with a trailing slash) and it works. Case closed!

Comment: Do you still have a problem, or is this fixed now?

Comment: For this case, maybe using the enum type is better.

Comment: Because "If the parameter is in "path", this property is required .... " https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/406#issuecomment-305575804 there are a couple of hacks around, but then the output swagger.json would not conform to the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have do it via path you could:

```
[Route("{isEven}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetData(bool isEven) => DoGetData(isEven);

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetData() => DoGetData(isEven: null);
```

This gives you:

```
.../api/Mathematics/GetData/true
.../api/Mathematics/GetData/false
.../api/Mathematics/GetData
```